# Updating rails while working with Docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to update some gems including `rails`.

How can a run `bundle install` while working with `Docker`.

My Docker files looks like this:

```
 FROM ruby:2.4.1
 RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
 RUN mkdir /myapp
 WORKDIR /myapp
 ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
 ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
 RUN gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc && bundle install
 ADD . /myapp
```

Comment: How do you run rails in development?

Comment: What do you mean? I just run docker-compose up to run my application